# Disable logging for specific controller actions in Rails 4.2 using Loggly and lograge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Our Rails logs are filled up with status pings from our load balancer, and it would be great to filter those out.

We want all other endpoints to be logged, but we'd like to be able to turn off application logging for this controller alone.

The controller looks like this:

```
class V2::StatusController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :authenticate

    def ping
      head :ok, text: 'OK'
    end

end
```

Edit: Our logging is set up to send to Loggly:

```
require 'syslogger'
config.logger = Syslogger.new("APP_NAME", Syslog::LOG_PID, Syslog::LOG_LOCAL7)
config.lograge.enabled = true
config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Json.new
```

Comment: Did you try silencing the logger? put the body of ping method inside `Rails.logger.silence do .... end` ?

Comment: I tried that and it still logs. For reference, our logging is set up the loggly way:


    `require 'syslogger'`
    `config.logger = Syslogger.new("FIREHOUSE", Syslog::LOG_PID,Syslog::LOG_LOCAL7)`
  `config.lograge.enabled = true`
  `config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Json.new`

Comment: Have you tried using the lograge ignore configuration?

Comment: @Jonathan did lograge ignore actions configuration work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're using [lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge), This is from lograge's README for how to ignore actions:

> To further clean up your logging, you can also tell Lograge to skip log messages meeting given criteria. You can skip log messages generated from certain controller actions, or you can write a custom handler to skip messages based on data in the log event:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.lograge.enabled = true

  config.lograge.ignore_actions = ['home#index', 'aController#anAction']
  config.lograge.ignore_custom = lambda do |event|
    # return true here if you want to ignore based on the event
  end
end
```

So yours specifically would probably be

```
config.logger = Syslogger.new("APP_NAME", Syslog::LOG_PID, Syslog::LOG_LOCAL7)
config.lograge.enabled = true
config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Json.new
config.lograge.ignore_actions = ["v2/status#ping", ...]
```

Comment: Thanks! This appears to work in dev, I'll try it out in production tomorrow.

Comment: Tested in prod and this works like a charm. Thanks again.